# MySQL interprets system function call as schema function call (Error Code 1305: Function does not exist)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, geospatial, mysql-workbench, spatial

My problem is that MySQL detects my function call as something like a local schema stored procedure call. I'm not sure how to explicitly specify that this is a MySQL system function (or otherwise how should I change the SQL).

My SQL code is:

```
set @p = GeomFromText('POINT(32.8303610 34.9743380)');
select OBJECTID FROM demog_yishuv_stat08_publish
where ST_Contains(demog_yishuv_stat08_publish.Shape, @p);
```

The response I get is:

```
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION mySchema.ST_Contains does not exist
```

**ST_Contains** is however a MySQL function, not defined inside mySchema. [This is the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains) for ST_CONTAINS.

Any help: greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using MySQL 5.6.1 or later.  ST_Contains was added in 5.6.1.   From the doc you cited:

> As of MySQL 5.6.1, corresponding versions are available that use
>   precise object shapes. These versions are named with an ST_ prefix.
>   For example, Contains() uses object bounding rectangles, whereas
>   ST_Contains() uses object shapes.

Previous versions of MySQL provide a Contains function which uses the MBR of the two geometries, not their exact shape, for the test.   This may work for you if you are unable to upgrade MySQL.